# Where is database stored - Cordova-sqlite-storage

Tags: cordova, android-sqlite

Please don't mark this duplicate. I searched a lot and have gone through number of posts before posting this.
I am working on Cordova. I have an android 5.1.1 device on which I am testing the app. 
I opened a database by using following code -

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'});
```

This worked well and also I could perform CURD, but, I am not able to locate the database either on device or in my application folder on my laptop.
I don't have rooted device. Also could not locate /data/data//databases/ in my application folder.

Where can I find the database file ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really ancient post, but I just checked the "default" db location option using the `cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free` plugin, and the database showed up in:

`/data/user/0/<app name>/files/`

I'm guessing the other flavors of the cordova sqlite plugins would save things in the same directory.